# GestureDetector onHorizontalDragUpdate repeat invoke problem

Tags: flutter

I am using GestureDetector to capture the right slip in flutter, when detect the gesture of the finger swip from left to right, exit the page. this is the flutter version info:

```
$ ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter --version
Flutter 1.22.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9b2d32b605 (5 weeks ago) • 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
Engine • revision 2f0af37152
Tools • Dart 2.10.5
(base)
```

this is the code I am using now:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container()
)
```

this is the function to handle finger positions:

```
Offset _initialSwipeOffset;
  Offset _finalSwipeOffset;

  void _onHorizontalDragStart(DragStartDetails details) {
    _initialSwipeOffset = details.globalPosition;
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    _finalSwipeOffset = details.globalPosition;
  }

  void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    if (_initialSwipeOffset != null) {
      final offsetDifference = _initialSwipeOffset.dx - _finalSwipeOffset.dx;
      if (offsetDifference < 0) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
  }
```

but when I swip finger from left to right in the screen. the `onHorizontalDragUpdate` function invoke many times and the `_initialSwipeOffset` is null when run to `_onHorizontalDragEnd` function. This is my full code of the page:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
            16.0,
          ),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 500.0,
            child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => {},
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text(
                      item.subName == "" ? "Comment" : item.subName,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
              if (item.isFav == 1)
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0, right: 1),
                  child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 50,
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: RaisedButton.icon(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Feather.check_circle,
                          size: 16,
                          color: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
                        ),
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        onPressed: () => touchSub(item.id.toString(), SubStatus.UNSUB),
                        label: Text("已订阅"),
                      )),
                )),
              if (item.isFav != 1)
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8.0, right: 1),
                  child: ButtonTheme(
                      minWidth: 50,
                      height: 30.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        onPressed: () => touchSub(item.id.toString(), SubStatus.SUB),
                        child: Text("订阅"),
                      )),
                )),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage(username: item.author)),
                  );
                },
                child: RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: item.author,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
              if (item.content != "")
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Html(
                  data: item.content,
                  style: {
                    "body": Style(
                      fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                    ),
                  },
                  onLinkTap: (url) => CommonUtils.launchUrl(url),
                )),
              SliverPadding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                sliver: viewService.buildComponent("articlelist"),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ));
```

where is the problem and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: if you want to detect "right swipe" just use `DragEndDetails.velocity` / `DragEndDetails.primaryVelocity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomSrollView is actually stealing the touches. I will provide you with a solution.

#### 1. Extend `HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer`

```
class AllowMultipleHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer
   extends HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer {
 @override
 void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
   acceptGesture(pointer);
 }
}
```

#### 2. Use `RawGestureDetector`

```
RawGestureDetector(
          gestures: {
            AllowMultipleHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer:
                GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                    AllowMultipleHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer>(
              () => AllowMultipleHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer(),
              (AllowMultipleHorizontalDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                instance.onStart = _onHorizontalDragStart;
                instance.onUpdate = _onHorizontalDragUpdate;
                instance.onEnd = _onHorizontalDragEnd;
              },
            )
          },
          child: ....,
```

If you are using `empty container` as a test, add some color to it
`Container(color: Colors.transparent)`

Comment: It works, could you tell me more information ? @YoBo

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: what‘s the meaning of CustomSrollView stealing touch? why your solution could work but I am using could not? @YoBo

Comment: Scroll view also have `GestureDetector`, by default, only one can receive touch - the ScrollView. With the solution I posted, you have both working, Yours and the one in the Scroll view.